# Datetime binding from Jquery datepicker to MVC problems

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

we use the JQuery UI Datepicker.

When i enter the date in this format: 9/22/2012 asp.net MVC says it is not in a valid format.

When i look at the viewmodel which is filled via the binding, it says for the datefield: `NULL`.

When i look at the request, i see this as the posted value: `9%2f22%2f2012`

in the `protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext))` I've set Culture like this

```
            CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo(language.LanguageISO);
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
```

where `language.LanguageISO` is, in this case, '`en`'

I thought that the model binder would pick up the culture?

Can it be that it is a problem that the  slash in the date is escaped as `%2f`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's too late to set the culture in the `OnActionExecuting` event. The model binder has already ran at this stage. You need to set it earlier, before the model binder runs. For example you could implement the `IAuthorizationFilter` interface:

```
public class SomeCustomAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        // TODO: set the culture here so that it's picked up by the model binder

        CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo(language.LanguageISO);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Darin, you scare me, you know just too much, this indeed did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

try to configure datepicker like

```
$('.has_datepicker').datepicker({

       dateFormat: '@System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern.Replace("M", "m").Replace("yy", "y")'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Follow the step:
1. @Html.TextBox("date", Model.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), new { @class = "date" })

2.
/// <reference path="jquery-1.4.4.js" />
/// <reference path="jquery-ui.js" />
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.date').datepicker({dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"});
});
```